# Show that fiber products exist in the category of abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-groups

Show that fiber products exist in the category of abelian groups. In fact, If $X, Y$
are abelian groups with homomorphisms $f: X \to Z$ and $g: Y \to Z$ show that 
$X \times_z Y$ is the set of all pairs $(x, y)$ with $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ such that $f(x) = g(y)$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you prove that $X \times_Z Y$ as defined in the last sentence has maps to $X$ and $Y$ so that the appropriate square from the definition commutes?  That's the start to your problem; after that, you can deal with the universal property.

Comment: Since you are *told* one group that will work as a fiber product, what you really need to do is show that the given set/group has the universal property property of the fiber product.

Comment: This is exercise 50(a) in chapter 1 of Lang's *Algebra*, verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You definitively know that $\mathbf{Ab}$ has products and equalizers (kernels). Use this to show that it has fiber products by constructing the fiber product construction as the equalizer of some product of maps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Y,Z$ be three abelian groups. Put $X\times_Z Y$ as given in the exercise, defining multiplication pointwise, then indeed $p_1,p_2$ are both morphisms. Then, let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary element in $X\times_Z Y$, then $f\cdot p_1(x,y)=f(x)=g(y)=g\cdot p_2(x,y)$, hence the required diagram commutes. Now suppose any other group $T$ has this property, with maps $h_1,h_2:T\to X,T\to Y$, then put $l:T\to X\times_Z Y$ to be $l(t)=(h_1(t),h_2(t))$ where $t\in T$. Clearly the projections of $X\times_Z Y$ commutes with $l$ and $f\cdot h_1(t)=g\cdot h_2(t)$ for any $t\in T$, hence we simply need to show the uniqueness of $l$. Let $m$ be any other morphism. Suppose WLOG that $m(t)=(k_1,k_2)$ with $k_1\neq h_1(t)$ for some $t$, then $p_1\cdot m(t)=k_1\neq h_1(t)$ and hence the diagram does not commute, and hence $l$ is unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think Lang is simply incorrect. If you let $Z$ be the trivial group, and let $X$ be non-trivial, then there will not be a unique map from $X\times Y$ to itself that makes the required diagram commute. Am I making a mistake here?

Comment: Do you mind checking my answer and see if it answers your doubt?